# not calling mousemove event on widgets and graphics view

Tags: c++, qt, qgraphicsview

I have created a set of wizard pages inherited from qwizardpage. in one of my wizard page i have a graphics view and in that using graphics scene and a qrect a rectangle has been created and now i am trying to catch the callback event of mouse move when the mouse is in the graphicsview area, but outside this area only call back is happening. But mouse press event is functioning properly. could anyone suggest me any solution.

```
WizardPage::WizardPage(QWidget* parent)
{
    m_pScene = new QGraphicsScene(this);
    graphicsView->setScene(m_pScene);

    m_pRect = new QRect(-25, 25, 100, 40);
    m_pScene->addRect(*m_pRect);
     setMouseTracking(true);
}

void EgoLeverWizardPage::mouseMoveEvent(QMouseEvent *event)
{
    qDebug() << "move";
}
```

Comment: `graphicsView->setMouseTracking(true);` might help, though. You should track mouse on graphics view, but you enabled tracking on your wizard page only.

Comment: @vahancho: Not working.

Comment: Last chance - try the same for the viewport: `graphicsView->viewport()->setMouseTracking(true);`, because graphics view is a scroll area.